# Can a focused practitioner throw a death curse?

Tags: dresden-files

Wizards are explicitly able to throw a death curse, in the events of their deaths in this setting. The "Your Story" also describes this "wizard ability".

However, if the players kill a powerful enough focused practitioner: is it possible that this practitioner could throw a curse at one of them as well, if they have the opportunity? Assuming that the focused practitioner has some sort of ritual ability focus, considering that a death curse is mechanically a ritual of sorts, as opposed to an evocation sorcerer.

Or is it wizard exclusive by the universe/rpg rules?

What I have found in the rulebook appears to suggest that, but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with the lore.

The term "wizard" is a little fuzzy in Dresden Files terms. Sometimes it is used to mean "trained by the white council" and sometimes "has magical power on par with the white council".

The vampire Marvra is usually referred to as a sorceress, but Ebenezar said. "If she's got a wizard's power, she might well be able to level a death curse at you when she goes down."

So, a death curse is something that requires magical power (and ability), not something specific to a Wizard of the White Council.

And then if we look at the rules:

> The wizard’s death curse is actually very easy to model. It’s a ritual, but with all of the preparation ready to go. The components of preparation are the circumstances of the wizard’s death—all of the consequences he has can be tagged, and he can inflict more upon himself if he’s got the space, since he’s not going to be around afterward.

So anyone who can perform a ritual (either through full access to Thaumaturgy or with a suitable pick for the Ritual stunt) can, in theory, unleash a death curse.

It will, of course, be limited by their skills and aspects.